# I need to handle overlapping dates but if the end date is null then it to be assumed that the process has not stopped

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, gaps-and-islands

I have a start date and end date of a process from two different sources.these two sources will  be merged and the dates needs to be handled in case of conflicts

### Dataset1

```
 P_startDate    P_EndDate  
 1-Jan-07        1-Jun-15
```

Dataset2

```
P_Start Date    P_End Date  
1-Mar-15          1-Jan-17  
2-Jan-17           Null
```

Merged Dataset / Expected Dataset

```
 | Process Start Date | Process End Date  |
 | 1-Jan-07           |  1-Mar-15         |
 | 1-Mar-15           |  1-Jan-17         |
 | 2-Jan-17           |  Null             |
```

I did create a code but that is giving me a result where the null (no end date) condition is not considered and my out put comes as

```
| Process Start Date |  Process End Date  |
| 1-Jan-07           |  1-Mar-15          |
| 1-Mar-15           |  1-Jan-17          |
| 1-Jan-17           |  2-Jan-17          |
```

I have followed the guidelines from here
 http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#overlapping.dates

```
with D (ID, bound) as (  
    select   ID   
       , case T when 's' then StartDate else EndDate end as bound  
    from  (  
    select ID, StartDate, EndDate from so.A   
    UNION  
    select ID, StartDate, EndDate from so.B  
    ) as U  
    cross join (select 's' as T union select 'e') as T  
)  
select P.*
from (  
    select s.ID, s.bound as StartDate, min(e.bound) as EndDate    
    from D as s join D as e   
    on s.ID = e.ID   
    and s.bound < e.bound  
    group by s.ID, s.bound  
 ) as P  
 left join so.A as a  
 on  P.ID = a.ID   
 and a.StartDate <= P.StartDate and P.EndDate <= a.EndDate  
 left join so.B as b  
 on  P.ID = b.ID   
 and b.StartDate <= P.StartDate and P.EndDate <= b.EndDate  
 order by P.ID, P.StartDate, P.EndDate
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I don't get the logic.  What happened to the period `1-Mar-15`-`1-Jun-15` ?

Comment: Are you able to update the data sets directly? In other words, if you are pulling from sources and storing a copy locally, can you do a join and update the end dates that overlap? If not, you could do the same thing storing to a temp table. Afterward, you don’t have any overlaps and you combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like a merge overlapping interval problem. Here is one solution that keeps a running count of starts and ends:

```
CREATE TABLE ds1 (P_STARTDATE DATE, P_ENDDATE DATE);
CREATE TABLE ds2 (P_STARTDATE DATE, P_ENDDATE DATE);

INSERT INTO ds1 VALUES
('2007-01-01', '2015-06-01');

INSERT INTO ds2 VALUES
('2015-03-01', '2017-01-01'),
('2017-01-02', NULL);

WITH cte1(d, v) AS (
    SELECT P_startDate, +1 FROM ds1 UNION ALL
    SELECT P_EndDate,   -1 FROM ds1 UNION ALL
    SELECT P_startDate, +1 FROM ds2 UNION ALL
    SELECT P_EndDate,   -1 FROM ds2
), cte2(d, c) AS (
    SELECT d, SUM(SUM(v)) OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, d)
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY d
), cte3(d, c, f) AS (
    SELECT d, c, CASE WHEN LAG(c) OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, d) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM cte2
), cte4(d, c, g) AS (
    SELECT d, c, SUM(f) OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN d IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, d)
    FROM cte3
)
SELECT MIN(d) AS FromDate, CASE WHEN COUNT(d) = COUNT(*) THEN MAX(d) END AS ToDate
FROM cte4
GROUP BY g;
```

Result:

```
FromDate               ToDate
01/01/2007 00:00:00    01/01/2017 00:00:00
02/01/2017 00:00:00    02/01/2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: no use of that ..the enddate of the last result in cases where the end date is supposed to be null is coming as the last date and not null

Comment: Oh... looks like a merge overlapping intervals problem.

Comment: my query gices exactly that result but what i need is for the last date there should not be any end date

Comment: @Arnit made a small change, see revised answer.